# Basic function related question

Tags: functions

This is a super simple question, I'm just confirming that the answer key I was provided with has it wrong.

> Identify the function $$f(x) = x(a^x - 1)/(a^x - 1).$$
> Is it an odd, even, polynomial function or none?

It's an odd function right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please don't pay attention to that bot. What was the answer key? Cannot this (odd) function be also considered as polynomial?

Comment: Yeah it states that it's a polynomial function. It's both though, right?

Comment: One could argue that this is not a (*real*) function at all in the normal sense (*over the real numbers*) since it is not defined for $x=0$.  (*Even though there is a removable discontinuity at $x=0$, strictly speaking it is still a part of the function*).  Assuming one were to talk about whether or not it is a function over $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ instead, it is equal at every point to the much simpler function $f(x)=x$ which is an odd polynomial function over this more restrictive domain.

Comment: It is an odd function, but not an odd polynomial function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it yes an odd function:
Assuming $x \neq 0$ then $f(-x)= -x \frac{a^{-x}-1}{a^{-x}-1}= -x = -x \frac{a^{x}-1}{a^{x}-1}=-f(x)$ and for $x=0$ it is not defined. This is true assuming $a>0$.

Comment: Agreed that you don't want $~a < 0,~$ since then $~a^x~$ is not always defined.  However, you also need $~a \neq 1.$

Comment: Thank you. I really thought I was missing vital information; both of your guys' answer cleared my doubt.